# Dynamically load all modules within a directory and add it to a list in Python

Tags: python-3.5

I have a directory (and sub directories) that contain Python files. Each file contain only 1 class.

Here an example

`commands/ping.py`

```
class Ping:
    def __init__():
        print('works')
```

What I want to do is something along the lines of:

```
commands = []

def load_commands():
    for name in os.listdir('/commands'):
        module = import name
        for key, value in module:
            print(key, value) #-> "Ping", ClassObject
            if isClass(value):
                commands.append(Value()) #where value is the class
```

Is this possible to do in Python3.5? What are some suggestions on how to achieve this if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import inspect
import importlib

def load_commands(self):
    for directory in os.listdir('{0}/commands/'.format(self._config['root_directory'])):
        if (directory != "__init__.py" and directory != "__pycache__"):
            for file in os.listdir('{0}/commands/{1}'.format(self._config['root_directory'], directory)):
                if (file != "__init__.py" and file != "__pycache__"):
                    path = "commands.{0}.{1}".format(directory, file[:-3])
                    module = inspect.getmembers(importlib.import_module(path))

                    for key, value in module:
                        if (inspect.isclass(value) and issubclass(value, Command) and not key == "Command"):
                            self._commander.add(value())
```

I solved it using the above code. Posting it if anyone want to do the same in the future.